# Getting ADUser's manager when that manager is a contact. not an account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script running to get all accounts and their managers and output to a csv.
I'd like to get the Manager's employeeID and UserPrincipalname

This works fine for Managers which are accounts, but sometimes a person's manager is a contact, because they are managed by someone from a different office (not in our local AD).

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=accounts,ou=production,dc=int" -filter * -properties * | select  GivenName, Name, Surname, UserPrincipalName, employeeID, @{Name='AccountExpirationDate';Expression={$_.AccountExpirationDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}}, Department, Title, @{Name="ManagerID";Expression={(get-aduser -property employeeID $_.manager).employeeID}}, @{Name="ManagerEmail";Expression={(get-aduser -property employeeID $_.manager).UserPrincipalname}} |  Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\ME\Desktop\ALL_AD_Accounts_HQ.csv
```

I know I can get contacts with something like the following:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'employeeID -eq "001" -and objectClass -eq "contact"'
```

But I can't seem to marry these two concepts. How can I get the user's manager info if it's a contact and not an account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't get all of this as a one-liner (unless you love crazy long lines of code..), but I would loop over the found users to do something like below:

```
# Get-ADUser by default returns these properties:
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName

$allUsers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=accounts,ou=production,dc=int" -Filter * -Properties Department, Title, EmployeeID, AccountExpirationDate, Manager
foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
    # create an empty Hashtable for the two manager properties
    $manager = @{ID = $null; Email = $null }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.Manager)) {
        # try and get an ADObject from the Manager property (= DistinguishedName)

        # Get-ADObject by default returns these properties:
        # DistinguishedName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID

        # if you're worried about distinghuishedName containing characters like a single quote (O'Brian)
        # you can use the -Identity parameter:
        try { $mgrObject = Get-ADObject -Identity $user.Manager -Properties mail, EmployeeID -ErrorAction Stop }
        catch {$mgrObject = $null}

        # using the -Filter would not need a try{..} catch{..}
        # $mgrObject = Get-ADObject -Filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$($user.Manager)'" -Properties mail, EmployeeID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        if ($mgrObject) {
            # test if this is a contact or a user object
            switch ($mgrObject.objectClass) {
                'user'    { 
                    # if it's a user, perform another Get-ADUser call
                    $mgr = $mgrObject | Get-ADUser -Properties EmployeeID, EmailAddress
                    $manager['ID']    = $mgr.EmployeeID
                    $manager['Email'] = $mgr.EmailAddress  # or if you prefer UserPrincipalName
                }
                'contact' {
                    # if it's a contact use the properties we already have in the $mgrObject
                    $manager['ID']    = $mgrObject.EmployeeID
                    $manager['Email'] = $mgrObject.mail

                }
            }        
        }
    }
    # output an object with all properties you want in the csv
    $user | Select-Object  GivenName, Name, Surname, UserPrincipalName, EmployeeID, 
                           @{Name='AccountExpirationDate';Expression={$_.AccountExpirationDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}}, 
                           Department, Title, 
                           @{Name="ManagerID";Expression={$manager['ID']}},
                           @{Name="ManagerEmail";Expression={$manager['Email']}}
}

# output the results to CSV file
$result | Export-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\ALL_AD_Accounts_HQ.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

AFAIK these are all properties you can get for contacts using Get-ADObject:

```
CanonicalName, Description, DisplayName, DistinguishedName
givenName, legacyExchangeDN, mail, Name, initials, sn, targetAddress
Title, Department, Division, Company, EmployeeID, EmployeeNumber
StreetAddress, PostalCode, telephoneNumber, HomePhone, mobile, pager, ipphone
facsimileTelephoneNumber, l, st, cn, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, co
mailnickname, proxyAddresses, msExchRecipientDisplayType
msExchRecipientTypeDetails, msExchRemoteRecipientType, info
```

Comment: Thanks so much Theo! This looks great, but I was hoping to use the employeeID attribute to search for the manager contact instead of distinguished name, to avoid issues with having to escape characters in names like O'Brien. Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: @Sylvie Well.. the `.Manager` property is either empty or it contains the `DistinguishedName` of the manager, so at that point we do not have an EmployeeID to use in a `-Filter`. I have edited my answer to use that property using the `-Identity` parameter, which will need a `try{..} catch{..}`.